# Why HTML <button type="submit" >doesn't work with internet explorer?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, button, browser

I work on a **CMS** called Jahia, and I'm trying to display  a list of files from an XML list with buttons wich call Actions to display the file.

```
<Files>
    <CdFile>
      some info about the file path , filename ...
    </CdFile>

   <CdFile>
some info about the file path , filename ...
    </CdFile>
   <CdFile>
some info about the file path , filename ...
    </CdFile>
</Files>
```

it works fine with mozilla browser but with Internet explorer the list is displayed but the buttons inside does'nt works.  Any Idea ? I think that the problem is with the list of , maybe IE don't use it like the others browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="jcr" uri="http://www.jahia.org/tags/jcr" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="utility" uri="http://www.jahia.org/tags/utilityLib" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" uri="http://www.jahia.org/tags/templateLib" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="functions" uri="http://www.jahia.org/tags/functions" %>


<jsp:useBean id="displayList" class="org.jahia.modules.connect.displayList" scope="request">
            <jsp:setProperty name="displayList" property="userID" value="10" />


</jsp:useBean>


  <form action="<c:url value='${url.base}${currentNode.path}.Connect.do'/>" method="post" id="ContactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    </form>
<table id="table_id" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="left" bgcolor="#999999">>
  <caption> Files of current user</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Directory</th>
        <th>file Name</th>
        <th>document type</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

        <c:forEach items="${displayList.test}" var="CdFile">
            <tr>
                <td><button name="subject" form="ContactForm" type="submit" value="${CdFile.path}">Download</button></td>
                <td>${CdFile.folder}</td>
                <td>${CdFile.fileName}</td>
                <td>${CdFile.docType}</td>
                <td>${CdFile.date}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've hardcoded the value of userID for testing

there is the javabean called to read the XML and then create the list of files

```
public class displayList{
  private String userID;
  private String pathToXML = "C:\\Users\\adm_fjousse\\Desktop\\serviceWin$test\\CnD_1000\\" ;
    FileList fileList = new FileList();
  private List<CdFile> test = new ArrayList<CdFile>();
  public void setUserID(String userID){
    this.userID = "ID"+ userID;
    this.pathToXML = this.pathToXML + this.userID + ".xml";

    startSocket();
  }

  public String getUserID(){
    return this.userID;
  }
   public List<CdFile> getTest(){
    return this.test;
  }

  public void startSocket(){

        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;

        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()  ;
        String xml = "";
        try{
            //D'abord le client se connecte et attend un message.
            Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.232.12.6"),2008);
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
            //String message_distant = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("1================================");
            //Puis il dit qui il est 
            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.println(userID);
            out.flush();

            //Ensuite le serveur va lui envoyer le fichier correspondant en fonction de son ID
            transfert(sock.getInputStream(),baos, true);
            System.out.println("size ===="+ baos.size());
            System.out.println(userID);
            xml =baos.toString("UTF-8");



            xStream.alias("CdFile", CdFile.class);
            xStream.alias("files", FileList.class);

            xStream.addImplicitCollection(FileList.class, "fileList");

            System.out.println("2================================"+ xml);
            this.fileList = (FileList)xStream.fromXML(xml);
            System.out.println(fileList);   
            this.test = fileList.getFileList();
            System.out.println("3================================");    
            sock.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
   }
  public static void transfert(InputStream in , OutputStream out, boolean closeOnExit ) throws Exception{
    try{byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n;

        while((n=in.read(buf))!=-1){
        System.out.println("============loop");

            out.write(buf,0,n);

            out.flush();
            }
        out.close();
       }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

  }
```

There is the Action called to display the file, when there is an onclick call:

```
public class Connect extends Action{
  @Override
    public ActionResult doExecute(HttpServletRequest req, RenderContext renderContext, Resource resource,
                                       JCRSessionWrapper session, Map<String, List<String>> parameters,
                                       URLResolver urlResolver) throws Exception{
             System.out.println("11212================================");

        HttpServletResponse r = renderContext.getResponse();

        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;
             System.out.println("first================================");

        String fileToSend = parameters.get("subject").get(0);
        System.out.println(fileToSend);
        System.out.println("1================================");
        try{
            //D'abord le client se connecte et attend un message.
            Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.232.12.6"),2008);
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
            //String message_distant = in.readLine();
            //System.out.println(message_distant);
            //Puis il dit qui il est           
          System.out.println("1================================");

            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.println(fileToSend);
            out.flush();
                      System.out.println("2================================");

            //Ensuite le serveur va lui envoyer le fichier correspondant en fonction de son ID
            transfert(sock.getInputStream(),r.getOutputStream(), true);
            renderContext.setResponse(r);
          System.out.println("3================================");

            sock.close();

       }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
   return new ActionResult(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, null,  new JSONObject());//,null, generateJSONObject(clientNode));
   }
  public static void transfert(InputStream in , OutputStream out, boolean closeOnExit ) throws Exception{
    try{byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while((n=in.read(buf))!=-1){
            out.write(buf,0,n);
          System.out.println("4================================");

            out.flush();}  
       }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
  }
```

Serverside class

```
public class ClientService extends Thread
{
    Socket sockClient;


    /*******************************************/
    public ClientService(Socket client)
    {
        sockClient = client;
        start();
    }

    /*******************************************/
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockClient.getInputStream()));
            //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sockClient.getOutputStream());

            String distantMsg = in.readLine();
            if(distantMsg.contains("ID") && distantMsg.length() < 15) {

                String fileToSend = "C:\\Users\\adm_fjousse\\Desktop\\output\\"+ distantMsg +".xml";
                Commun.transfert(new FileInputStream(fileToSend),
                        sockClient.getOutputStream(),
                        true);




            }
            else{
                String fileToSend = distantMsg;
                Commun.transfert(new FileInputStream(fileToSend),
                        sockClient.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
            /*out.println("service running : "+(new Date()));
            out.flush();
            out.close();*/
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {}

        try
        {
            sockClient.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {}

        sockClient = null;
    }
}

class Commun{
        public static void transfert(InputStream in , OutputStream out, boolean closeOnExit) throws IOException{
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while((n=in.read(buf))!=-1){
            out.write(buf,0,n);
            out.flush();
        }
        if(closeOnExit){
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
     }
    }

[my fina
```

l view with mozilla works][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIQvK.png)

Comment: Since JSP is not read on the browser, this is not coming from there, the JSP is read on you application server.

Comment: @AxelH yes I know, but the button and the action will be the same after the server processing

Comment: So this is a Javascript / JQuery problem, the `jsp` tag as nothing to do here (like the title referencing JSP) This is javascript or HTML problem with Internet explorer. Is there an error in the console of the browser ?

Comment: Okay I've edited my post.

Comment: This is still not reproducible for anyone who doesn’t have your server-side setup & data available. Show us a testable live version - jsfiddle or something. Please also go read [mcve].

Comment: `input` is not a valid value for the [`type` attribute of the `<button>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type).

Comment: @CBroe is it ok right now ?

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: Why is your form end tag immediately after the form start tag instead of after the form controls that should (presumably) be inside it?

Comment: IE 11, sorry type="input" was an error on the title :)

Comment: Because you're not forced to put the button inside the form, you can specify wich form you want to call with form="id"

Comment: Yeah, but _that_ is not supported by IE yet. Presumably your whole problem would not exist, if you just put the form elements inside the form …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some reading, you use a button to submit the form.
So you can find the problem here, in the Browser Support table
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

You use the form attribute of Button. This is not supported on IE. You should use this instead

```
<input type="submit" value="Download"/>
```

And put your table into the form.

EDIT : Well, there is a lot of comment since a Start reading ^^ Quentin, if you write your answer, I will remove mine ;)

Comment: Okay thanks you @AxelH, is there a solution to display a button with a label different of the value for example : Value = "c:\blalblabla\file.txt" and the button display download ?

Comment: @cryckx value is use to set the text of the "button", but you can use a data-* attribute to set this url.

Comment: This comment is a lifesaver! For IE11 as well.